# Which code i should write in respect to delete the list item as well as from database by using context menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

In my code i want to delete a selected item from the list view and from the database. I am using Context Menu. I am getting the position list.

CODE:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    // Track track = (Track)mAdapter.getItem(info.position);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Deleted" + menuInfo.position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // delete(menuInfo.id);

        return true;
    case R.id.add:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.view:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Viewed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    default:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

[image]

I am getting only position but can not find the name, description, date and money that is in the image. How can i find one of then so that by using name date or money i can delete the list from list view and from database.

Comment: but i dont have any database helper class. i use database connectivity in this class

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the record you don't need any of the information you are asking about, all you need is the row ID of the record in the database, and you can get that from the context menu by using `menuInfo.id` in your `onContextItemSelected` method.

Example:

```
case R.id.delete:
    deleteItem(menuInfo.id);  //  Your delete method with the paramter of the row id
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Deleted" + menuInfo.position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
```

delete method (presumably in your database helper class):

```
public boolean deleteItem(long rowId) {
    return mDb.delete(YOUR_TABLE, YOUR_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: but i dont have any database helper class. i use database connectivity in this class @Barak

Comment: Well, it's still the same.  You feed the rowId to whatever method you use to delete your record (or even just use it right there), and you get the rowId by using the menuInfo.id.

Comment: please see this link 
stackoverflow.com/questions/12971815/context-menu-in-list-view-using-base-adapter-with-database/12971974#12971974
this is my class

Comment: i have table MONEY so how to write in the code i dont know YOUR_ROWID. @Barak

Answer (score 0):

see I have faced the same problem earlier

so my solution to you is

```
View yourView; 

        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            yourView = (TableRow) v; // here you can have your own view in my case i have Table row
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.table_row_menu, menu);  

        }
```

And further once you get the view you will get the information with the help of **`tag`** associated with view